# OpenGL issue in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

So I've encountered this issue in libgdx, saying that my opengl version is outdated. But the thing is, it requires at least opengl 2.0, but my graphics driver supports opengl 4.0, so I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. The IDE I'm using is Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" 
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the 
FBO extension is required. OpenGL version: 1.1.0
Type: OpenGL
Version: 1:1:0
Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
Renderer: GDI Generic
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.initiateGLInstances(LwjglGraphics.java:347)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.initiateGL(LwjglGraphics.java:226)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:217)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:144)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

I'm using windows 10 with intel HD graphics 4000

Comment: How do you create the window and the context?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a pretty old PC/laptop then.

I had this same issue about 2 weeks go and found a driver patch on [a LWJGL issue](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/119) which fixed this problem for me.

Scroll to the very very last comment to find a patch for a laptop or for a PC.
Extract the patches and replace some of the driver files with them before adding the driver.